# Why is null std::optional considered less than any value, not more

Tags: c++

Is there any math sense in having null std::optional being less than any keeping value? Or is it made only for consistency and there would have been no any difference if it was "more" instead of "less"?

Comment: I think it is arbitrary, although you can always find reasons after the fact. Say it is consistent with the order you get after casting to bool.

Comment: If it's off any consequence, the default comparison in C++ library is `<`. And by "default" usually everyone wants "nothing" to be ordered before "something".

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I do not agree. My default would be compilation error for example. How can you compare something you do not have, with something you have? Why should it be less? What if that value type could not be negative, and now because of this implicit behavior I am allowing the code to have something less than 0?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 I don't understand what you mean. If your value type cannot be negative, it should be in the definition of the type not the `optional`. The `optional` either has a value or it doesn't. If you don't want to compare "nothing" with something, then don't program that. But if you do, then this is the default behavior - which you can customize. For example delete the specializations for your specific optional type.

Comment: I mean that it can be very weird to suddenly introduce automatically values that can be less than 0 just because I want some value to cover the possiblity that it might not exist. In my view, `nullopt` is an undefined state, which cannot be compared to a defined state. It is either something you do not have or something you do not know anything about. I normally threat it as a compile time checkable uninitialized value. I do not like that it is threated by default as a comparable value. Only operators like == and != should be defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Directly from [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#rationale.relops) (emphasis mine):

> A number of ways of including the disengaged state in comparisons have been suggested. **The ones proposed, have been crafted such that the axioms of equivalence and strict weak ordering are preserved**: disengaged `optional<T>` is simply treated as an additional and unique value of `T` equal only to itself; this value is always compared as less than any value of `T`.

Further on it says

> Value `nullopt` could have been as well considered greater than any value of `T`. The choice is to a great degree arbitrary. We choose to stick to what `boost::optional` does.

---

Taking a look at `boost::optional`'s take on this, we get from [its documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/relational_operators.html):

> In a similar manner, type `optional<T>` is `LessThanComparable` whenever `T` is `LessThanComparable`. The optional object containing no value is compared less than any value of `T`. To illustrate this, if the default ordering of `size_t` is `{0, 1, 2, ...}`, the default ordering of `optional<size_t>` is `{boost::none, 0, 1, 2, ...}`. This order does not have a practical interpretation. The goal is to have any semantically correct default ordering in order for `optional<T>` to be usable in ordered associative containers (wherever `T` is usable).

So no, there is no "maths sense" to this all except for "nothing is less than something". It's an arbitrary choice of no practical consequence only to ensure the type can be used in ordered containers without much hassle.

Comment: It has practical consequences. For example, I have a function which was returning a value, and I decide that value sometimes might not exist. I change the function to return `optional<T>`. In my tests, I am using `auto result = f()`, and I am comparing that returned value to be `>` than some threshold. Not only it compiles, but also my tests will not be broken when the function under test returns `nullopt`.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 if it returns `optional`, then it shouldn't you first check if it has a value?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk sure I should, what I am saying is that I am not enforced by the compiler to also refactor the test in this case, cause `operator>` would be automatically available by default, and its behavior might not necessarily be what I want or expect.